# Declare length of int column

Tags: magento2.3, upgradeschema, database-schema

How can I declare a size for an `int`?

I have the following code:

```
...
    /** @var \Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface $schemaSetup */
    $table = $schemaSetup->getConnection()
            ->newTable($this->schemaSetup->getTable('my_new_table'));

    $table->addColumn('id', Table::TYPE_INTEGER, null, [
        Table::OPTION_IDENTITY => true,
        Table::OPTION_NULLABLE => false,
        Table::OPTION_PRIMARY => true,
        TABLE::OPTION_UNSIGNED => true,
    ])
    ->addColumn('quote_id', Table::TYPE_INTEGER, 10, ['length' => 10])
...
```

But when the SQL is output it generates the following:

```
`quote_id` int NULL COMMENT 'Quote_id'
```

What I want is:

```
`quote_id` int(10) NULL COMMENT 'Quote_id'
```

Answer (score 0):

You do no say what kind of object is variable "$table" it is hard to provide an accurate answer.

If I see some examples on the internet like this one here https://meetanshi.com/blog/add-column-to-existing-database-table-in-magento-2/

The third parameter in function "addColumn" is an "array" and in your case you simply put the value "10"